# MonoTouch localization using Resources from Desktop

Tags: c#, localization, xamarin.ios

We have a desktop app that we're trying to "port" to iPad using Monotouch.

For the Desktop all the localization strings are put into the resource files, and we have a separate resource .dll for each language (standard Visual Studio way).

What are the possibilities to reuse that with MonoTouch?

The standard iOS way is using .lproj folders, and we can generate them from our resource dll's, but may be there are better options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use resx files - you can find a sample project [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3708#c0).

There is also [vernacular](https://github.com/rdio/vernacular), which looks interesting, but I haven't actually tried it myself.

Comment: Thanks, the sample project helped a lot :)